# a large navigation menu in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a large navigation menu, like a website header(Top logo, Bottom some menu buttons.) and this navigation menu must shown in every view of my application (like a masterpage, header(this navigation) will be static but content will change). What is the best way to represent this menu in my application?

I thought UINavigationBar may be appropriate but I am not sure about it. Can I customize it that much?

Comment: Consider the sliding menu implementation used in facebook app. You can use some [custom implementation](https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu) for this

Comment: I also use a sliding menu. What I am looking for a static navigation menu option on the top of app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

totally depends on how much is 'that much'.

you can use UIToolBar for more customization that what UINavigationBar allows, but you'll have to do some extra work in getting that functionality to match that of a nav bar,

or use a customViewController that has this largeNavigationMenu, and use it as a baseClass for all viewControllers you are using in your app.

Comment: I think a customViewController will work. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to use some kind of container controller. Either a UINavigationController, a UITabBarController or maybe something custom like a drawer menu controller. Depends on the app design.